# Kotlin: Calling a function from another class

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to create a button that plays sound using SoundPool. The sound is created in another class and i'm trying to access it from my MainActivity as follow:

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var soundPool: SoundPool? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val sound1 = SoundEngine().load(this, R.raw.ahem_x, 1)//<-error pop up at load

        button1.setOnClickListener { soundPool!!.play(sound1, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f) }

    }

}
```

Sound class:

```
class SoundEngine() {

    private var soundPool: SoundPool? = null

    fun someCode():Int{
        soundPool = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                .build()
            SoundPool.Builder()
                .setMaxStreams(1)
                .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                .build()
        } else {
            SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0)
        }
        val sound1 = soundPool!!.load(MainActivity(), R.raw.ahem_x, 1)
        return sound1

    }
}
```

I'm getting an error at `val sound1 = SoundEngine().load(this, R.raw.ahem_x, 1)` in MainActivity with pop up error `Unresolved reference load`. I googled about this and was overwhelmed by the information and got further confused. Please point me in the right direction. Thank in advance.

Comment: can you add the error logs as well as the soundEngine class code full

Comment: Umm, maybe I misunderstand what you're doing, but I think your method in `SoundEngine` is called `someCode` and you're trying to call it as `load`?

Comment: @zamb13, yes... is it possible?

Comment: in that case, it should give him compile-time error, not runtime I guess. @zsmb13

Comment: "Unresolved reference" sounds like a compile time error in the IDE. @JoeShamuraq: if you want to use your method with the name `load`, you have to use that name at its declaration as well, instead of `someCode`.

Comment: @zamb13, can you give me example... so sorry for the trouble...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your implementation like below:

**Sound class:**

```
class SoundEngine {

    private var soundPool: SoundPool

    init {
        soundPool = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                .build()
            SoundPool.Builder()
                .setMaxStreams(1)
                .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                .build()
        } else {
            SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0)
        }
    }


    fun load(context: Context, rawId: Int, priority: Int):Int {
        return soundPool.load(context, rawId, priority)
    }

    fun play(soundID: Int, leftVolume: Float, rightVolume: Float, priority: Int, loop: Int, rate: Float) {
        soundPool.play(soundID, leftVolume, rightVolume, priority, loop, rate)
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var soundPool: SoundPool? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val soundEngine = SoundEngine()
        val sound1 = soundEngine.load(this, R.raw.ahem_x, 1)

        button1.setOnClickListener { soundEngine.play(sound1, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f) }

    }

}
```